# Ошибка сокета при изменении сети

Tags: java, android, сокет, timeout

После переключения сети (например, с Wifi на мобильную сеть), сокет выдает ошибку

```
class java.net.SocketException
                   recvfrom failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
```

Может есть какой-то способ отследить изменения сети?
И можно ли как-то однозначно определить, где изменения в сети, а где обычная ошибка сокета по таймауту?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Может есть какой-то способ отследить изменения сети?

Да, способ есть.

При изменении состояния подключения `ConnectivityManager` посылает [соответствующее](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION) broadcast message, которое можно отловить и обработать данную ситуацию.

Comment: Note: В Android Nougat эти broadcast messages получаться будут только в активном режиме приложения (https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html)